# Django Objects of Objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So, I am trying to pull data into a form. Right now I have a Class set up like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  #some other variables that do stuff and are just static types.
```

I am trying to create a form that enables the updating of data in the `user` variable of my Player class but I can't figure out how to even get to that data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your case `user` its not variable, it is instance of class `User`, what data do you want to update?

Comment: Have you created a form object yet?  Django needs a model, and a form object (which can be based on that model), which is then passed to your template.  Have a look at the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/), it's very good on forms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your code, though maybe you are open to an alternative model design such as `Player` inherits `User`.

`class Player(User):
    #some other variables that do stuff and are just static types.`

This way you could easily create a Player `ModelForm`.